# PackageManager - fast way (batch way) to retrieve a lot of infos at once

Tags: android, package-managers, android-package-managers

Currently I'm retrieving the app names of an icon packs apps like following:

```
final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo ai;
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
{
    try
    {
        ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(data.get(i).packageName, 0);
    }
    catch (final PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        ai = null;
    }
    data.get(i).label = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : data.get(i).packageName);
}
```

Can this be improved? It's damn slow and I'm wondering if there is any way to make a batch query instead of 100s of single queries...

Comment: it is damn slow since it needs some AIDL calls to get the info from the service - all you can do is a background processing

Comment: I'm doing that already, was just curious if the loading could be improved via batching the queries...

Comment: no, there is no such way: package manager service does not provide such a feature